# Target the correct directory using set_include_path in PHP (Amazon MWS Api)

Tags: php, amazon-mws

using the .config.inc.php file in my Amazon API library.
When I was working the samples directory which is in the following location..

```
/var/www/libraries/amazonfba/FBAOutboundServiceMWS/Samples
```

It used the current configuration in the file (which worked fine).

```
/************************************************************************ 
    * OPTIONAL ON SOME INSTALLATIONS
    *
    * Set include path to root of library, relative to Samples directory.
    * Only needed when running library from local directory.
    * If library is installed in PHP include path, this is not needed
    ***********************************************************************/   
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../.');    
    
   /************************************************************************ 
    * OPTIONAL ON SOME INSTALLATIONS  
    * 
    * Autoload function is reponsible for loading classes of the library on demand
    * 
    * NOTE: Only one __autoload function is allowed by PHP per each PHP installation,
    * and this function may need to be replaced with individual require_once statements
    * in case where other framework that define an __autoload already loaded.
    * 
    * However, since this library follow common naming convention for PHP classes it
    * may be possible to simply re-use an autoload mechanism defined by other frameworks
    * (provided library is installed in the PHP include path), and so classes may just 
    * be loaded even when this function is removed
    ***********************************************************************/   
     function __autoload($className){
        $filePath = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
        $includePaths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
        foreach($includePaths as $includePath){
            if(file_exists($includePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePath)){
                require_once $filePath;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now i didn't want to keep my code in 'samples' thinking it would be a easy move.
My .config.inc.php file is now located at

```
/var/www/integrations
```

Im getting errors about the classes because I presume it is trying to reference them in the wrong location.

I think it is to do with this line...

```
 set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../.');
```

But however I change that it does't work? Anyone point me in the direction to correctly point it to my directory or some pointers on how it works? I also noticed the commenting state this would be ignored on PHP, in which case how could i point it in the right direction then?

Update:
I have tried adding the directory to the array like follows:

```
        $includePaths[4] ='/var/www/libraries/amazonfba';
```

which on var_dump gives the correct location but then gives me this...

```
Warning: require_once(FBAOutboundServiceMWS/Client.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/integrations/AmazonFBA/.config.inc.php on line 78
```

This is because these files such as client.php refer back to the include location set I think.
I cannot get my headache the locationing and just can't get it right! Any pointers so my php file + the config file (in the same folder) can be in a seperate folder to the library would be ace!

Answer (score 0):

The path listed of `'../../.'` looks like a relative path, relative to the `Samples` directory. If you moved the code, that relative path would also need to change accordingly.

In your PHP code, you can add the library to your PHP include path [as described here](http://www.php.net/set_include_path) to make it visible.

Also, make sure that you include `src/MarketplaceWebService/Client.php` in your PHP file.

Comment: Sure, but what exactly does '../../.' mean? I am aware that I can that the include path and I have tried playing with it - haven't had much luck, could i hardcode the directory in to that? Are you able to provide code examples?

Comment: '../../.' means two folders above the current folder, which was set in the context of the folder structure for the sample. Can you try using a full path?

Comment: Could I have just var_dumped 'get_include_path' before and after that change and got the following results.

    string(13) ".;C:\php\pear"


    string(21) ".;C:\php\pear;../../."

Comment: Why is it refering to c php pear? is that a temp location that my php code is stored in?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Have you already tried including a full path, and including the Client.php file?